# Lebesgue Integral Property: $f \leq g \implies \int_E f \,d\mu \leq \int_E g \,d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am learning measure theory by myself. Upon arriving at a property
of Lebesgue integral of nonnegative functions, I doubt my own proof
on it. On the other hand, I am not convinced by the proof presented
on my literature. Here I present the property and my attempt on
proving it.

> $\textbf{Theorem} \text{ (A Property of Lebesgue Integral).}$
> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let
> $f: X \to [0, \infty]$ and $g: X \to [0, \infty]$ be measurable
> functions. Let $E \in \mathcal{A}$. Then we have the following
> expression:
> $$
>     (\forall x \in X) \,\big[ f(x) \leq g(x) \big]
>     \implies \int_E f \,d\mu \leq \int_E g \,d\mu
> $$

Here is my attempt on proving the theorem.

> $\textit{Proof.}$ By simple function approximation theorem, we
> have measurable simple functions $s_k : X \to [0, \infty)$
> and $t_k : X \to [0, \infty)$ such that
> $$
>     0 \leq s_1(x) \leq s_2(x) \leq \dotsb \leq f(x)
>     \, \land \,
>     \lim_{k \to \infty} s_k(x) = f(x)
> $$
> and
> $$
>     0 \leq t_1(x) \leq t_2(x) \leq \dotsb \leq g(x)
>     \, \land \,
>     \lim_{k \to \infty} t_k(x) = g(x) \,,
> $$
> for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. And let $m_k, n_k \in \mathbb{N}$
> such that we define
> $$
>     \mathrm{image}(s_k)
>     := \{\alpha_{(k,\, 1)}, \dotsc, \alpha_{(k,\, m_k)}\}
> $$
> and
> $$
>     \mathrm{image}(t_k)
>     := \{\beta_{(k,\, 1)}, \dotsc, \beta_{(k,\, n_k)} \}
> $$
> for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we also define
> $$
>     \forall j \in \{1, \dotsc, m_k\} \,,\;
>     A_{(k,\, j)} := {s_k}^{-1}(\{\alpha_{(k, j)}\})
> $$
> and
> $$
>     \forall j \in \{1, \dotsc, n_k\} \,,\;
>     B_{(k,\, j)} := {t_k}^{-1}(\{\beta_{(k, j)}\}) \,,
> $$
> for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we express
> $$
>     s_k = \sum_{j = 1}^{m_k} \alpha_{(k,\, j)} \chi_{A_{(k,\, j)}}
> $$
> and
> $$
>     t_k = \sum_{j = 1}^{n_k} \beta_{(k,\, j)} \chi_{B_{(j,\, k)}} \,,
> $$
> where $\chi$ is the indicator function. Now suppose
> $$
>     \forall x \in X \,,\; f(x) \leq g(x) \,.
> $$
> Since $s_k$ is non decreasing and converges to $f$, we have
> $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} s_k = \lim_{k \to \infty} s_k = f$. The same
> applies to $t_k$. Hence we obtain
> $$
>     \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} s_k
>     = \lim_{k \to \infty} s_k
>     = f
>     \leq g
>     = \lim_{k \to \infty} t_k
>     = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} t_k \,,
> $$
> which implies
> $$
>     \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
>     \sum_{j = 1}^{m_k} \alpha_{(k,\, j)} \chi_{A_{(k,\, j)}}
>     \leq
>     \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
>     \sum_{j = 1}^{n_k} \beta_{(k,\, j)} \chi_{B_{(j,\, k)}} \,.
> $$
> Then
> \begin{align}
>     \int_E f \,d\mu
>     &= \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \int_E s_k \,d\mu \\
>     &= \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
>         \int_E \sum_{j = 1}^{m_k}
>         \alpha_{(k,\, j)} \chi_{A_{(k,\, j)}} \,d\mu \\
>     &= \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \,
>         \sum_{j = 1}^{m_k} \alpha_{(k,\, j)}
>         \int_E \chi_{A_{(k,\, j)}} \,d\mu \\
>     &= \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \,
>         \sum_{j = 1}^{m_k} \alpha_{(k,\, j)} \,
>         \mu\left( E \cap A_{(k,\, j)} \right) \\
>     &\leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \,
>         \sum_{j = 1}^{n_k} \beta_{(k,\, j)} \,
>         \mu\left( E \cap B_{(k,\, j)} \right) \\
>     &= \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
>         \int_E t_k \,d\mu \\
>     &= \int_E g \,d\mu
> \end{align}
> proves the theorem. $\quad \Box$

Now what concern me: "did I make some mistakes in the proof?";
"are there better and satisfying proofs for the theorem?".

Your helps will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. Just saw that you do assume $f,g\ge 0$. Therefore my answer was irrelevant, or take it as an extenstion of the theorem to drop the condition $f,g\ge 0.$ ( The proof of yours looks totally OK).

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for the answer, it's insightful. Grateful if my  proof is okay. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The property that $\int_E f\,d\mu$ is the supremum of integrals of simple functions holds in general only for nonnegative $f\,.$ So you look at
$$
f=f^+-f^-\text{ and }g=g^+-g^-
$$
and note that $f\le g$ implies $f^+\le g^+$ and $f^-\ge g^-.$ Your proof implies
$$
\textstyle\int_E f^+\,d\mu\le\int_E g^+\,d\mu\quad\text{ and }\quad\textstyle\int_E g^-\,d\mu\le\int_E f^-\,d\mu
$$
which implies $\int_E f\,d\mu\le\int_E g\,d\mu.$